# Update project based on Symfony 2.0 to Symfony 2.2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to update my project written in Symfony 2.0 into Symfony 2.2.

Moving source codes into 2.2 project ended with `config.yml` and `security.yml` incompatibiliy.

Is there way how to properly migrate Symfony 2.0 project into Symfony 2.2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It better to wait until Symfony 2.3 before migrating. It will be released [somewhere in May](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#schedule). It's [the first LTS](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#long-term-support-releases) (Long Time Support) release, meaning that it's maintained for *three* years. So: You don't have to worry about BC breaks for 3 years!

For the migrating of Symfony 2.0 to 2.3: There is nothing you can do. Read the `UPGRADE-*.md` files (which are stored in the root of the `symfony/symfony` package) and fix anything that is in their in your code. Every BC break that's important for normal users will be put in those UPGRADE files.

If you can't solve it after the fixing everything in the UPGRADE files, you should take a look at the `CHANGELOG.md` files in the root of the package (e.g. the `symfony/security` package). Try to find something that is changed and cause your code to break.

Finally, if you don't get your script working, there are a lot of active Symfony2 users who are waiting to help you. Take a look at [the community page](http://symfony.com/community) and find your place to ask questions.