# Symfony migration from 2.0 to 2.2 or wait 2.3 LTS?

Tags: symfony, migration

We actually want to migrate our 2.0.23 Symfony application to 2.2. But as the release of the 2.3 version is quiet near (may 2013) we are wondering if it's not better waiting for this major as It is a LTS ? Which is very important for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better is to wait until the [Long Time Support](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#long-term-support-releases) version [is released](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#schedule). [It](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-3-what-s-next?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20symfony/blog%20%28Symfony%20Blog%29) will be maintained for 3 years according to the release model.

**Update,**

Possible duplicate > [Update project based on Symfony 2.0 to Symfony 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602057/update-project-based-on-symfony-2-0-to-symfony-2-2)

Comment: In 2.3 a bunch of depreciated functions will be removed.  In 2.2 these functions still exist but will generate warning messages in the profiler. I suspect it might be easier to go to 2.2 since your app should still run after the configuration options are updated.  From 2.2 to 2.3 should be trivial.